# Identifying a center with squared distance function in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, least-squares

I can't figure out how to solve the following problem in plain JavaScript.

I have a set of numbers, (e.g. 5, 10, 35, -30, 3), and I am looking for the 'center' of these numbers. My center is supposed to be the point where the sum of the squared distances to all other points is minimal. I think it's the one-dimensional version of the problem of least squares.

Any help would be appreciated. I do not need exact results so a heuristic approach might work as well. It has to work with negative values though.

Comment: How would you get an answer with pencil and paper?

Comment: Its a one dimensional array. Sort the array and center is arr[start] - arr[end] / 2

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to pick any real number, then the number you seek is the mean of your numbers.

If you have to pick from a restricted subset (eg integers, or one of the original numbers) then you want the element from that subset that is closest to the mean.

Both of these assertions follow from:

```
Let Q(y) = Sum{ 1<=i<=N | (X[i]-y)*(X[i]-y}
If m = Sum{ 1<=i<=N | X[i]}/N (ie the mean)
then for any d
Q(m+d) = Q(m) + N*d*d
```